# Can not find the tag library descriptor for http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets

Tags: jsp, jsf, facelets, taglib

I've a JSP with

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" prefix="ui" %>
```

However it errors with

> The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application

I have libraries `facelets-lib.jar` and `jsf-facelets-1.1.10.jar`, which I suppose is Facelets, but they do not contain JSP taglib descriptors.

What file is correct?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Facelets is intented to **replace** JSP altogether. But yet you're attempting to declare it as a JSP taglib. This is never going to work. Both are distinct view technologies. Facelets is a XML based view technology which is designed to be a successor of JSP. In Java EE 6 which was released december 2009 it has already replaced JSP as standard view technology for JSF and JSP has since then been deprecated.

You need to rename file extension from `.jsp` to `.xhtml` and replace all JSP taglib declarations by XML namespace declarations and remove all `<jsp:xxx>` tags and all `<% %>` scriptlets.

So, for example the following basic JSP template `page.jsp`

```xml
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib prefix="f" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"%>
<%@taglib prefix="h" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<f:view>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <title>JSP page</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h:outputText value="JSF components here." />
        </body>
    </html>
</f:view>
```

has to be rewritten as `page.xhtml`

```xml
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
    <head>
        <title>Facelet page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h:outputText value="JSF components here." />
    </body>  
</html>
```

Finally, the mentioned JAR files are Facelets 1.x JARs while Facelets 2.x is already been out since 2009 as part of [a JSF 2.x implementation](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/). If you can, I'd strongly recommend to just skip Facelets 1.x and continue with Facelets 2.x.

#### See also:

- [Facelets Developer Documentation](http://facelets.java.net/nonav/docs/dev/docbook.html) (for Facelets 1.x)
- [Java EE 6 tutorial - Facelets](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giepx.html) (for Facelets 2.x)
- [JSF 2.0 tutorial with Eclipse and Glassfish](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/01/jsf-20-tutorial-with-eclipse-and.html) (to start from zero)
- [Migrating from JSF 1.2 to JSF 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441713/migrating-from-jsf-1-2-to-jsf-2-0)

Comment: Hi, @BalusC, i'm thinking about your post. And trying to understand the impact this would cause.

Everybody knows the scriptlet is unfashion. But if i have the same both page like your example. Can the simples `<% %>`scriplet impact in performance? 

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If you are using JSF 2, you will need the `jsf-api.jar` and the `jsf-impl.jar`.
If you are using JSF 1, look at [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-facelets/)