# Can't find tag library descriptor

Tags: java, eclipse, jsf

Yesterday I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6915509/eclipse-cant-find-tag-lib-descriptor-for-jsf-project-being-imported-from-cvs) question about not being able to find the tag descriptor for the JSF core libraries. Now I am importing another project and I'm getting the same error of "Can't find tag library descriptor", only this time it's on the last line of this snippet:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=windows-1252"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" prefix="h"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" prefix="f"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk" prefix="t"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://javascript4jsf.dev.java.net/" prefix="j4j"%>
```

The jar is included in the WEB-INF->lib folder, and I just can't get the error to go away. My server won't even start with this project in there because it errors out. How can I resolve this error message?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ended up changing my taglib declaration to this way and then I got no errors.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
        xmlns:t="http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk"
        xmlns:j4j="http://javascript4jsf.dev.java.net/">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look inside the the j4j jar, is the TLD in there? If so, does the TLD have taglib uri that matches the uri you posted?

Comment: This may seem like a stupid question, but how am I supposed to look inside the jar?

Comment: JAR is basically a ZIP file with a predefinied folder structure. So, any ZIP or RAR tool can open JARs.

Answer (score 0):

I had issues with TLD files when using WebSphere.  Even though the TLD file was in the jar in question (in my WEB-INF/lib directory) my application could not find it.  My solution was to create a WEB-INF/tld directory and pull the TLD files out of my jars and put them in my tld directory.

Also, check in the j4j tld file to confirm that you are using the correct URI.