# JSF beginning + Installation UI error

Tags: java, jsf

I am trying to start with JSF installation.

In JSF file, I just added **h tag** and **f tag**.
Once I do `<f:view>` it gives below error.

```
    May 30, 2012 2:49:20 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.faces.webapp.UIComponentClassicTagBase.setJspId(UIComponentClassicTagBase.java:1858)
    at org.apache.jsp.ClinicInformation_jsp._jspx_meth_f_005fview_005f0(ClinicInformation_jsp.java:98)
    at org.apache.jsp.ClinicInformation_jsp._jspService(ClinicInformation_jsp.java:70)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:374)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:342)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:267)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:849)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:454)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

I can't understand what is missing. I added two Jars...

1. javax.faces-2.1.8.jar
2. javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api-1.2.1.jar
3. primefaces-3.2.jar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The stacktrace indicates that you're using the old and deprecated JSP for some reason. JSP has been succeeded by Facelets since JSF 2.0 end of 2009.

Rename `ClinicInformation.jsp` to `ClinicInformation.xhtml` and read the [Facelets tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giepx.html). For some kickoff examples how such a Facelets file should look like, check the following answers:

- [Can not find the tag library descriptor for http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6322127/can-not-find-the-tag-library-descriptor-for-http-java-sun-com-jsf-facelets/6322355#6322355)
- [How to include another XHTML in XHTML using JSF 2.0 Facelets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792862/how-to-include-another-xhtml-in-xhtml-using-jsf-2-0-facelets/4793959#4793959)
- [Migrating from JSF 1.2 to JSF 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441713/migrating-from-jsf-1-2-to-jsf-2-0/4532870#4532870)

Note that you *can* configure JSF 2.0 to use JSP instead by some `web.xml` params, but this is absolutely not recommended as it's an inferior view technology. Even more, PrimeFaces doesn't support JSP at all.

Comment: Ohh ok Balus... I need to read more then... But once everything is configured fine. I can start further... But thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks BalusC. I am always fan of your comments... It's always helpful to me.. when I converted .jsp to .xhtml everything worked fine but my help in eclipse tool using CTRL + Space is no more now. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10807291/eclipase-not-giving-any-help-on-ctrl-space

Is there any way to start it?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem when calling the app not using the string faces.

Example:

1. `http://ADDRESS:PORT/APP/JSP`
2. `http://ADDRESS:PORT/APP`

But the issue was gone after using `http://ADDRESS:PORT/APP/faces/JSP`.
What type of URL are you using?

Hope this helps.