# eclipse not giving any help on CTRL + Space

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, jsf, facelets

When I was using .jsp file in eclipse was giving me help for tags...

Where I was adding taglibs...

```
<%@ taglib prefix="h" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="f" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" %>
```

Now I converted `.jsp` to `.xhtml` in which I can't add above taglibs instead I have to use

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3c.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui">
```

In this case eclipse doesn't give me any help on CTRL + Space.
Is there any way to start those help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse doesn't have buitin Facelets tooling (yet). So far only the [Glassfish Server plugin](http://glassfishplugins.java.net/eclipse36/index.html) and the [JBoss Tools plugin](http://www.jboss.org/tools) comes with Facelets tooling.

Based on your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10806915/jsf-beginning-installation-ui-error) you're using Tomcat, so JBoss Tools should do (and it is actually more feature rich than the Glassfish Server plugin). Go in Eclipse to *Help > Install New Software*. Assuming that you're using the current Eclipse Indigo SR2 version, enter the following URL in there:

> http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/indigo/SR2/

Wait until the list of options loads and finally pick and install the "JBoss Web and Java EE Development" option.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, based on your previous question you've installed PrimeFaces 3.2. But yet you're using the old PrimeFaces 2.x XML namespace URI. Fix it as well:

```
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
```

Comment: Ohh!! Great BalusC. Thank you very much. You are Einstine.