# NullPointerException in generated JSP code calling setJspId()

Tags: jsp, jboss, nullpointerexception

I am trying to deploy the Duke's Bank example form the Java EE 5 tutorial on JBoss 7.1.1.  I have only used (unaltered) the source, and the standard XML configuration files for deployment, part of the exercise here is to see how I might structure a JSP based project of my own.

The exception I get is as follows:

```
  ERROR [[jsp]] Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.faces.webapp.UIComponentClassicTagBase.setJspId(UIComponentClassicTagBase.java:1858) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at org.apache.jsp.main_jsp._jspx_meth_f_005fview_005f0(main_jsp.java:99)
    at org.apache.jsp.main_jsp._jspService(main_jsp.java:76)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:326) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:253) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:397) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636) [rt.jar:1.6.0_18]
```

I have not given any JBoss configuration files, the WAR's WEB-INF part looks like this:

```
$ jar tvf build/lib/dukebank-web.war 
     0 Sat Dec 15 22:00:12 GMT 2012 META-INF/
   123 Sat Dec 15 22:00:10 GMT 2012 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
     0 Sat Dec 15 22:00:12 GMT 2012 WEB-INF/
  2514 Fri Dec 14 14:29:20 GMT 2012 WEB-INF/web.xml
  1348 Sat Dec 15 08:19:46 GMT 2012 WEB-INF/dukesBank.tld
  7245 Sat Dec 15 08:19:46 GMT 2012 WEB-INF/faces-config.xml
  2153 Sat Dec 15 08:19:46 GMT 2012 WEB-INF/tutorial-template.tld
     0 Sat Dec 15 22:00:12 GMT 2012 WEB-INF/classes/...
```

The JSP file (main.jsp) that causes this problem is:

```
<f:view>
    <h:form>
        <jsp:include page="/template/template.jsp"/>
        <center>
            <h3><h:outputText value="#{bundle.Welcome}"/></h3>
        </center>
    </h:form>
</f:view>
```

The template file it includes:

```
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/tutorial-template.tld" prefix="tt" %>
<%@ page errorPage="/template/errorpage.jsp" %>
<%@ include file="/template/screendefinitions.jspf" %>
<html>
<head>
<title>
  <tt:insert definition="bank" parameter="title"/>
</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body bgcolor="#ffffff">
  <tt:insert definition="bank" parameter="banner"/>
  <tt:insert definition="bank" parameter="links"/>
</body>
</html>
```

I will refrain from coping any more files because, as I said at the start I haven't altered any of the files I have used.

Many thanks for your help,
Steve

Comment: Checkout lines 99 and 76 in the compiled JSP file `main_jsp.java` most chances are that `bundle` is null

Comment: @alfasin: this can impossibly produce this stacktrace. The `#{}` things are EL (`javax.el`) which doesn't appear in the trace at all and which is at its own also "null-safe".

Comment: @BalusC Cant he add before that line something like: `<%="bundle = "+bundle%>` ?

Comment: @alfasin: I'm not sure how doing that would be helpful in this particular question. I recommend to take some time apart to learn JSF/JSP if you're interested.

Comment: @BalusC if `bundle` is null then `bundle.Welcome` will throw a `NullPointerException` - no ? anyways, by viewing line 99 in the compiled JSP file main_jsp.java you should be able to find that the NPE is because of the `FacesContext` (like you wrote in your answer) which was my first suggestion...

Comment: @alfasin: you have apparently never used EL before. The answer to the OP's concrete question is already given below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Duke's Bank example is based on [JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info), which is a component based MVC framework which previously used to use JSP as "View". JSF pages are supposed to be opened by an URL which matches the `<url-pattern>` of the `FacesServlet` as definied in webapp's `web.xml`. For example, if it's `*.jsf`, then you should open it by `main.jsf` instead of `main.jsp`. Or if it's `/faces/*`, then you should open it by `faces/main.jsp` instead of `main.jsp`. This would invoke the `FacesServlet` which in turn will create the `FacesContext` and do all the JSF works.

You're getting a NPE on that line because the `<f:view>` (which is represented by the line `at org.apache.jsp.main_jsp._jspx_meth_f_005fview_005f0(main_jsp.java:99)` in the stack trace) is trying to find JSF's  `FacesContext`, but can't seem to find one. This is true, since the `FacesContext` is supposed to be created by the `FacesServlet`.

#### See also:

- [java.lang.NullPointerException at javax.faces.webapp.UIComponentClassicTagBase.setJspId](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13032224/java-lang-nullpointerexception-at-javax-faces-webapp-uicomponentclassictagbase-s)
- [What is the difference between JSF, Servlet and JSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095397/what-is-the-difference-between-jsf-servlet-and-jsp)
- [JSF in Java EE 5 tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnaph.html) (better: [JSF in Java EE 6 tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaph.html))

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem: the legacy Java EE 5 tutorial is not the right tutorial to read for JBoss 7. JBoss 7 is a modern Java EE 6 compatible container. [Since Java EE 6, JSP is **deprecated** as JSF view technology and succeeded by Facelets.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845032/wheres-the-official-jsp-tutorial) [Also, JSF 1.x (part of Java EE 5) is really not what you would like to use these days, you should be heading to JSF 2.x (part of Java EE 6)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3646940).

Comment: Many thanks for your help.  I am quite prepared to abandon my example in favour of the Java EE 6 tutorial if, as you point out, it is the newer way of doing things.  At the end of the day all I want is to learn an appropriate Java based server technology.