# Assign post variable to bean in JSF

Tags: jsp, jsf, tomcat7

Edited by post to try and explain what I am trying to accomplish.

I am trying to fill a field with a value sent by a post to the page. The input value is an ID that I want to insert into the field so the user does not have to fill out all the fields again.

```
<h:inputText value="#{bowlingEvent.ID}" />
```

What i am trying to do is simply.

```
bowlingEvent.ID = param['id'];
```

How is that done in jsf 2.x ?

Comment: Which jsf version is it?

Comment: Well not being an expert on taglibs and versions. At least I am using the 2.2 jsf (mojarra) in eclipse.

Comment: Do you need to use scriplets for any specific reason? Nowadays facelets is the way to go with modern jsf.

Comment: No I don't I need to assign the variable as I try to do. How it's done is not important.

Comment: I mean, you're mixing nowadays frameworks (jsf 2.2) with technologies that were released a decade ago. Isn't it easier to follow current jsf-facelets patterns? Unless you're playing with some legacy code, which I would consider not to upgrade to jsf 2.2 or definitely upgrade-rewrite everything. In short words, putting jsf 2.2 and scriptlets in the same plate will bring you headaches. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188706/how-to-avoid-using-scriptlets-in-my-jsp-page).

Comment: ok how would you suggest this code would look in the modern era?

Comment: For the parameters, see how [`f:viewParam`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888942/viewparam-vs-managedpropertyvalue-param-id) works. To replace your page with facelets, here you have [some tips](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6322127/can-not-find-the-tag-library-descriptor-for-http-java-sun-com-jsf-facelets).

Comment: Thanks that should probably do it :)