# docType parsing Error in jsf

Tags: html, richfaces

I am migrating richfaces 3.3.3 to richfaces 4.5.9 But when I added richfaces 4.5.9 jar  in project I am getting an Error as "The markup declarations contained or pointed to by the document type declaration must be well-formed."
my doctype declaration is

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:t="http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk"
xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"
xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j">
</html>
```

Comment: What is your jsf version? Did you also migrate to JSF 2.2? If so, then namespaces should be http://xmlns.jcp.org/ not http://java.sun.com/

Answer (score 0):

You Can try this one:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:t="http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk"
xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"
xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j">

<head>
  ..
</head>

</html>
```

please you can refer this all pages:

[Page 1](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/)

[Page 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6322127/can-not-find-the-tag-library-descriptor-for-http-java-sun-com-jsf-facelets)

[Page 3](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/ui/tld-summary.html)

[Page 5](https://myfaces.apache.org/core20/myfaces-impl/tlddoc-facelets/ui/tld-summary.html)

Comment: Sorry ...I went through all pages.....also copy and paste code from those pages in project but still not working....same code is working fine when I use richfaces 3.3.3 ....I think issue is related to richfaces 4.5.9  Thanks