# Can not validate an HTML generated from jsp

Tags: java, html, validation, jsp, xhtml

What's up? I've been using this site for a long time but now it's time for me to finally ask something. Here it goes:

I'm trying to validate an HTML genereted with a jsp and I'm getting this error:

```
there is no attribute "XMLNS"
<HTML xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><HEAD>
```

I know I can fix it with some stuff like that:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

But although I'm using this in my code the generated HTML becomes in this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><!-- Cabecera HTML --><HEAD>          
<META http-equiv="Expires" content="Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT">          
<META http-equiv="Last-Modified" content="Sun, 25 Jul 2004 16:12:09 GMT">
...
...
```

And this is part of my jsp code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
```

Do you guys have any ideas?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Add htmlxmlns tag below DOCTYPE as provided below and the try to open the HTML.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've got one question: what should I do with the namespaces (I mean those things: xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"

Comment: It defines an XML Namespace.

In your example, the Namespace Prefix are "ui","f","h" and the Namespace URI are "java.sun.com/jsf/facelets","java.sun.com/jsf/core", "java.sun.com/jsf/html" 
In the document, you see elements like: <ui:insert>, <h:outputText value="" /> etc.   Check out these link on namespaces explanation: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_html.asp, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6322127/can-not-find-the-tag-library-descriptor-for-http-java-sun-com-jsf-facelets, https://www.sitepoint.com/xml-namespaces-explained/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using JSF and it may concern to some Mojarra bugs, e.g. https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2453
And if you are going to use xmlns for JSF components it's better to put your  layouts to xhtml pages, not jsp.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! By the way, I'm using jsf 1.2(we cannot update the version right now, company rules. It sucks.). If this is a java faces bug, I guess there's no way I can get the correct rendered HTML page. Am I wrong? Thanks again!